# Dev Console - Select Windows

Tags: developer-console, execute-anonymous, developer-productivity

I know that there is a keyboard shortcut for this, but it does not appear to be in the listed set. I want to change up which windows I see after Execute Anonymous, probably limiting it to back to just the execution log.

[image]

Which would work better for me to just look like:

[image]

Since it's mostly what I use that for. I am also curious what the other windows are useful for, but don't have a specific question to ask in that regard yet.

```
CTRL+O       Open
CTRL+G       Open log
CTRL+SHIFT+G Open raw log
CTRL+ALT+G   Download log
CTRL+S       Save the current view
CTRL+SHIFT+S Save all
CTRL+DELETE  Delete
CTRL+/       Close
CTRL+ALT+/   Close all
CTRL+E       Open the Execute Anonymous window
CTRL+ALT+E   Execute anonymous Apex code when the Execute Anonymous
             window is open or the last executed code when the window
             is closed
CTRL+P       View log panels...
SHIFT+ALT+G  Log panel
CTRL+SHIFT+? Show/Hide help for the shortcut key
CTRL+F       Find
CTRL+SHIFT+F Find/replace
CTRL+SHIFT+R Find/replace all
CTRL+SHIFT+H Search in files
SHIFT+TAB    Fix indentation
CTRL+SHIFT+O Open resource
SHIFT+ALT+G  Clear log panel
CTRL+J       Show Preview of the Visualforce page/component
CTRL+ALT+N   Navigate to the declaration of a selected object
             in the Source Code Editor
CTRL+SHIFT+L Show/Hide the Command Line Console
CTRL+,       Navigate backward through the view history
CTRL+.       Navigate forward through the view history
UP           Navigate backward through the open views CTRL+PAGE
DOWN         Navigate forward through the open views CTRL+PAGE
F11          Toggle full screen editing of the current view, if available
ESC          Exit full screen editing of the current view, if active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in asking this question I found the answer, but thought it might be useful to help someone else find it more quickly down the road.

```
CTRL+SHIFT+? Show/Hide help for the shortcut key
CTRL+P       View log panels...
```